# Road STI with MTB Derailleurs

Tags: shimano, shifter, derailleur-rear, compatibility

Not that this question hasn't been asked to death but I'm experiencing very poor shifting, here's my setup:

- Shifters: ST-5700 (10-Speed Road)
- Derailleur: M6000-SGS (10-Speed MTN)
- Cassette: Sunrace CSMX3 11-42T (10-Speed MTN)
- Adapter: Wolftooth Tanpan Inline 10-Speed (Mounted on cockpit)

My issues are shifting up into the middle ranges 18 - 24t, it's not very precise and I need to click the lever a little over. Then there's shifting down into the 11t which it struggles at times. Is there a way to solve this? I've tried mounting the tanpan on the derailleur, adjusting the barrel adjusters for better indexing but the shifting is never crisp and precise.

Comment: How old is the setup, especially cables? Using the tanpin, you are starting compromised, so everything else needs to be A Grade for a reliable setup.

Comment: Does this setup work with MTB shifter? Your derailleur is designed for max. 36T cassette, 42T is quite far outside the spec.

Comment: The system bumped this to the homepage, hence some minor additions. It's possible that the rear derailleur hangar has been bent, and a shop can check your derailleur alignment. That might cause the shifting symptoms described. Moreover, Wolf Tooth's specifications seem to say that you're limited to a 1x drivetrain with your cassette size, so make sure this is so. If you have not tried new cables, you absolutely should. And as stated, you are 6t over the max RD capacity. https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/products/tanpan

Comment: That silly adapter costs a significant fraction of what the inappropriate derailleur costs, and adds complication to your bike. A pair of cables with this gizmo spliced between them will not perform as well as a simple cable; it's just one more thing to troubleshoot when you have shifting issues. Why do people do this to themselves.

Answer (score 1):

`Shifters: ST-5700 (10-Speed Road)` and `Derailleur: M6000-SGS (10-Speed MTN)` will not work - the pull ratio is different.  You need a 9-speed Shimano MTB derailleur.  A 9-speed derailleur works directly with older Shimano 10-speed shifters, and shifting will be "normal".  (IIRC, some of the newer 10-speed, sub-105-level shifters use a different pull ratio.)

Comment: This is true, but the OP uses a Wolftooth Tanpan, which is specifically designed to solve this incompatibility.

Comment: @StefanS *specifically designed to solve this incompatibility* I was aiming more for others wanting to use a MTB derailleur with road shifters. Given the OP's stated issues, and especially given that a quick internet search indicates a Wolftooth Tanpan costs more than a decent 9-speed Shimano MTB derailleur alone, I think that's important.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but I still think you should add your comment into the answer.

Comment: @StefanS Probably wouldn't matter.  Finding out after the fact that a nine-speed rear derailleur that costs $35 would work better than a new $60+ 10-speed derailleur that also needs a $40 kludge/[Rube Goldberg contraption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg#Cultural_legacy) isn't going to go over well.  But hopefully this answer prevents someone **else** from going down this road.  I'd rather be useful than brownnose points just to boost my ego.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no 9 speed derailleur that will work with a 42t cassette